# enunciate to create docs for existing java REST API

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client, enunciate

i am using 'enunciate' for the existing Java REST (using Jersey) project.
i have build.xml and enunciate.xml: output file docs.zip is created but after unzip this file, i have:
css/ dir,
js/ dir,
robots.txt, model.html, index.html, favicon.ico, crossdomain.xml, application.wadl, apple-touch-icon.png files.

index.html and model.html do not have any docs from my java REST code.
Could anyone help me here?
I have no 'enunciate' experience.

Thanks,

---> this is one of REST code example:

@Path("/{spacecraftId}/log")

public class UserLogHandler
    implements ProcessCommunicationFacilityFailureListenerInterface,
               MessageCustomerInterface,
               IMessageAvailable
{

```
/**
 *  Retrieve log file information from MySQL database:
 *
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Response retrieveLogFromDatabase(
        @PathParam("spacecraftId") String spacecraftId,
        @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
{
}
```

}

---> the 'build.xml' file:

```
<!--The enunciate classpath points to all the jars in the "lib" directory.-->
<path id="enunciate.classpath">

 <pathelement path="${acmd-class-dir}:${mdasclasses.dir}"/>

  <fileset dir="/TPS/V19.0.2">
    <include name="xerces/xercesImpl.jar"/>
    <include name="xerces/xml-apis.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/jdom.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/mail.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/commons-codec.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/asm-3.1.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/jersey-core-1.7.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/jersey-server-1.7.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/jersey-client-1.7.jar"/>
    <include name="jdkaddons/jersey-multipart-1.7.jar"/>
  </fileset>


  <fileset dir="${enunciate.home}/lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>

  <fileset dir="${enunciate.java}"> 
    <include name="lib/tools.jar"/>
  </fileset>           

</path>

<!--define the task...-->
<taskdef name="enunciate" classname="org.codehaus.enunciate.main.EnunciateTask">
  <classpath refid="enunciate.classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<enunciate basedir="./" verbose="true" configFile="./enunciate.xml" >

  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  <classpath refid="enunciate.classpath"/>
  <export artifactId="docs" destination="./docs.zip"/>  
  <javacArgument argument="-g"/> 
</enunciate>
```

---> the 'enunciate.xml' file:

```
<api-classes>
    <include pattern="/tps/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>>

    <exclude pattern="com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam"/>
</api-classes>

<services>
    <rest defaultRestSubcontext="api">
    </rest>
</services>

<webapp disabled="true">
</webapp>

<modules>
  <disable-rule id="csharp.warnings"/>
  <disable-rule id="c-warnings"/>
  <disable-rule id="obj-c.warnings"/>
  <basic-app disabled="true"/>
  <c disabled="true"/>
  <csharp disabled="true"/>
  <jaxws-ri disabled="true"/>
  <obj-c disabled="true"/>
  <amf disabled="true"/>
  <gwt disabled="true"/>
  <jboss disabled="true"/>
  <object-c disabled="true"/>
  <rubby disabled="true"/>
  <jaxws-client disabled="true"/>

  <jersey disabled="false"/>

  <docs title="ICMD API"  docsDir="./" splashPackage="cmd.acmd_mdc_servlet" includeDefaultDownloads="true" includeExampleXml="false" disableRestMountpoint="true" copyright="copyright" forceExampleJson="true"/>
</modules>
```

Comment: problem fixed: i need to include the java package name within the <include pattern="..."/> under the <api-classes></api-calsses> tags.

Answer (score 2):

Your "include pattern" is incorrect. The "includes" refer to *classes*, not *jars*. So it might look something like:

```
 <include pattern="com.mycompany.api.resources.**"/>
```

Also, make sure all those classes are on your classpath when you invoke Enunciate.